# Carbon atoms types in amino-acids

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, amino-acids, carbon-family

I'm looking for a table or another kind of schema where I can find which type of carbon atoms (sp3, sp2 etc.) are present in each amino-acid.
In my biochemistry books these informations are not available.

I looked also on pubchem (e.g. [glycine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Glycine)), and I found some information about [alanine](https://brainly.com/question/9632337), [aspartic acid](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.clutchprep.com%2Fchemistry%2Fpractice-problems%2F107988%2Fconsider-the-structure-of-the-amino-acid-aspartic-acid-indicate-the-hybridizatio&psig=AOvVaw0GkHRSQFOu9q8kQlBF7uBV&ust=1618510685977000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCKjblZWt_u8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD), [methionine](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Oregon_Institute_of_Technology/OIT%3A_CHE_202_-_General_Chemistry_II/Unit_5%3A_The_Strength_and_Shape_of_Covalent_Bonds/5.3%3A_Valence_Bond_Theory_and_Hybrid_Orbitals/5.3%3A_Valence_Bond_Theory_and_Hybrid_Orbitals_(Problems)).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: For those who downvote my question, please specify why in order to improve it

Comment: Can you please provide a list of amino acids about which you want the information.

Comment: Hello @NisargBhavsar I'm interested in the 20 amino acids present in the proteins of our body.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but it is beneficial if you put how much work you have been done so far. Also, please clarify your info (e.g., see Nisarg Bhavsar's comment elsewhere).

Comment: For instance, carboxylic carbon  and carbonyl oxygen in glycine is $\mathrm{sp^2}$. The rest of the atoms in the molecule is $\mathrm{sp^3}$ ($\ce{C,N,O}$. It is more complicated than that but for your level of knowledge, this is good enough

Comment: Also remember, the oxygens on carbonyl groups in both structures (alanine and aspartic acid) you have just put are $\mathrm{sp^2}$.

Comment: It is not tabulated because you should be able to figure it out for yourself if you ever need to. If you pick up a good general chemistry textbook somewhere it will explain hybridisation. And there are lots of resources on the Internet to learn from, too. Mathew's comments are pretty much it, actually.

Comment: Hi @orthocresol ok maybe the informations I'm looking for are not so important to write them in a table. I'll try to retrieve them by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

| Sr. No. | Name | Structure | Hybridization and Number of Carbon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Serine | [image: Serine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=1\\sp^3=2$$ |
| 2 | Threonine | [image: Threonine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=1\\sp^3=3$$ |
| 3 | Tyrosine | [image: Tyrosine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=7\\sp^3=2$$ |
| 4 | Asparagine | [image: Asparagine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=2\\sp^3=2$$ |
| 5 | Glutamine | [image: Glutamine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=2\\sp^3=3$$ |
| 6 | Glycine | [image: Glycine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=1\\sp^3=1$$ |
| 7 | Alanine | [image: Alanine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=1\\sp^3=2$$ |
| 8 | Cysteine | [image: Cysteine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=1\\sp^3=2$$ |
| 9 | Valine | [image: Valine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=1\\sp^3=4$$ |
| 10 | Leucine | [image: Leucine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=1\\sp^3=5$$ |
| 11 | Isoleucine | [image: Isoleucine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=1\\sp^3=5$$ |
| 12 | Proline | [image: Proline] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=1\\sp^3=4$$ |
| 13 | Methionine | [image: Methionine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=1\\sp^3=4$$ |
| 14 | Phenylalanine | [image: Phenylalanine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=7\\sp^3=2$$ |
| 15 | Tryptophan | [image: Tryptophan] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=9\\sp^3=2$$ |
| 16 | Aspartic acid | [image: Aspartic acid] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=2\\sp^3=2$$ |
| 17 | Glutamic acid | [image: Glutamic acid] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=2\\sp^3=3$$ |
| 18 | Lysine | [image: Lysine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=1\\sp^3=5$$ |
| 19 | Arginine | [image: Arginine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=2\\sp^3=4$$ |
| 20 | Histidine | [image: Histidine] | $$sp=0\\sp^2=4\\sp^3=2$$ |

Comment: Fantastic table @NisargBhavsar

Comment: Which app you used to draw the structures?

Comment: @Eclipse239 I used the online interface at [py-chemist.com](https://py-chemist.com/mol_2_chemfig/home)